# Programmatically configure the values included in a managed metadata property

Tags: managed-metadata, configuration, managed-property

I've got a managed metadata property in PowerShell:

`Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty`

Looking on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497276%28v=office.12%29.aspx) I can't decide which property's responsible for the UI equivalent of "Include values from a single property...".

**EDIT:**

Clues I've found surrounding the issue:

That this particular member of the managed property I'm after is called `MergeCrawledProperties` and is managed using the `set-fastsearchmetadatamanagedproperty` method.

Comment: Is it more than "MergeCrawledProperties = true;" you're after?

Comment: I believe that's all I want to do. But, as discussed in the other thread, I'm having issues with the set-fastsearchmetadatamanagedpropertyso would just like confirmation that I'm barking up the right tree and that there would be a way to achieve this in the same PowerShell script. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The property I was after was the `RespectPriority` property. For some reason, it seems hardly documented.