# Including Assembly in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

Apologies if I'm missing something really basic here but in all the tutorials I've read that discusses the use of `set-fastsearchmetadatamanagedproperty`, it mentions how it belongs to the Administration.Schema namespace, but not how to reference this in a PowerShell script if you want to use `set-fastsearchmetadatamanagedproperty`!? I'm assuming referencing this namespace isn't done by default given the errors I get when running the script (about `set-fastsearchmetadatamanagedproperty` being an unknown).

Can somebody please give me a point in the right direction regarding the reference of a relevant namespace you want to use in a PowerShell script please?

Comment: Have you added the PS-Snapin *Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue* and are you running PowerShell as Administrator? Or have you forgot set ExcecutionPolicy to Bypass

Comment: I'm running PowerShell as administrator yes. It is the SharePoint Management Console so I though all of the snap in's were included by default?

Comment: True that... I don't see it either running *Get-Command | select-string -pattern "set"*

Comment: Are you a member of [FastSearchAdministrators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191232(v=office.14).aspx)?

Comment: I'm not sure, would that alter the visibility of the method in question? Would it not just refuse to run the method and throw a permissions exception?

Comment: The description in the link says you need to start "Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint shell" which is different from SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: I will ultimately need to deliver this to a client though who have access only to the standard SharePoint Management Shell. Thanks a lot for your help Benny.

Comment: Your welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SharePoint Management Shell but need to use **Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint shell**:

1. Verify that you meet the following minimum requirements: You are a member of the FASTSearchAdministrators local group on the computer where FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint is installed.
2. On the Start menu, click All Programs.
3. Click Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint.
4. Click Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint shell.

Reference: [Manage managed properties by using Windows PowerShell (FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191232%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Benny. That answers the question I asked here so I've marked it accordingly, but this is all in an effort to resolve the following post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/programmatically-configure-the-values-included-in-a-managed-metadata-property your insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll give it a shot after lunch :-) Thanx